# Is it ok to use Er. if a person is engineering degree holder

Tags: prefixes, honorifics

Its usual that we see doctors use Dr. Title, but I have also seen engineers use title - Er. Is this practise allowed, approved?

I have seen few name boards like that in India.

Comment: It's entirely dependent on the qualification. I've never seen it in English, though.

Comment: The question should be edited to specify a location. I suspect that the poster may be asking specifically about the situation in Germany, where many academic titles are tightly regulated by law.

Comment: location is India, editing the question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a cultural norm rather than the English language.

Comment: "Engineer" is not a formal title in the US.  If a person is a certified engineer or some such that would be shown as a qualification after the individual's name, as "John Smith, Registered Engineer", eg.

Comment: New age moderators are paranoic and ready to mark any thing duplicate. Wish I knew how to delete question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Europe, the approved title is Eur Ing, not Er.

It is permitted to engineers registered with one of the national engineering professional bodies.

For example, in the UK engineers must have achieved suitable qualification and registration with the  [IET](http://www.theiet.org/membership/profreg/international/eur-ing/)  or similar chartered organisation.  Similar organisations exist in other EU countries.

Use of a prefixed title like this is much more prevalent on the continent than in the UK or US, where postfixed letters such as CEng. are much more commonly used.

**Edit:**  The question has now been edited to refer to India.  I have seen "Engineer" as a prefix on Indian business cards and office doors.  *That* practice is not followed in Europe.  Simply having an engineering degree doesn't permit such a title, you just get to put BSc. (or similar depending on the university) after your name.

Comment: do you mean to say a person needs to register in a professional boby before we can use the Title Eur Ing

Comment: Yes. Eur Ing is *European Engineer* and is an EU-wide regulated qualification. The UK-specific version (which still requires registration, but costs less) is Chartered Engineer, denoted by the post-nominal letters CEng.

Comment: Indeed, the regulations are very much dependent on the jurisdiction. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_and_licensure_in_engineering for an overview of other countries.

Answer (score 0):

In Germany it is regulated by [law](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akademischer_Grad#Deutschland). So you can't just add "Dipl. Ing." if you are an engineer from outside Germany. 
A Dipl. Ing. is different from a Dr. since you can't have it in your passport. I've seen it as a door sign quite often.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Nepal, if they are registered in the Nepal Engineers Association, you can write ER.